# Get LINUX env variable with python

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, environment-variables

I have my ~/.bashrc file:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/

DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_HOST=localhost
```

When I'm doing **os.environ['PATH']** I get :

```
/usr/local/sbin
```

But when I'm doing **os.environ['DB_USER']** I get:

```
KeyError: 'DB_USER'
```

How I need to declare my vars correctly for python, cause echo in shell :

```
echo $DB_USER
    >>> postgres
```

thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't exported your variables:

```
export DB_USER=postgres
export DB_PASSWORD=password
export DB_HOST=localhost
```

Comment: Thanks, i think this is a solution!

Answer (score 0):

if you get `/usr/local/sbin` from  `os.environ['PATH']` this is an indication your .bash.rc did not run since you change the PATH there in the first line.

Any chance you did not restart bash before checking this?

Comment: i made source ~/.bashrc